# How to disable radiobutton's text from clickable feature?

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

I need to select radio button while touching only the icon of a radio button. By default when i touch on the radio button's text, the radio button also get checked.  How can i disable the feature?

```
   <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/optionGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="RadioButton"
                android:textColor="@color/optionText"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_exam"
                android:gravity="top" />           
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton"
                android:textColor="@color/optionText"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_exam"
                android:gravity="top"    />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton"
                android:textColor="@color/optionText"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_exam"
                android:gravity="top"       />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton"
                android:textColor="@color/optionText"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_exam"
                android:gravity="top"    />

        </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Why not make a custom control by extending RadioButton?

Comment: please post your xml code

Comment: xml code is updated @Phan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### To answer your question, you can't do it using the default `radiobutton` class.

The `android-radiobutton` is an object of the class which actually makes the radiobutton itself. This class sets the properties of the `RadioButton`, and, to a certain extent, you cannot change these properties. You can, however, make it unclickable, change the color, set the text, however, **you cannot change what portion of the button is clickable.** To do that, you must make your own class of a RadioButton, and extend it to the class that you are using.

[image]

Only way is by making your own class. Let me know if this answered your question.

:)

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple hack

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The problem with that solution is that if you have multiple radio buttons, you would be able to click them all at the same time, leaving you with something like a checkbox (you cannot uncheck though).